# Does Directx use the CUDA library for nvidia graphics cards?

Tags: cuda, directx, libraries, nvidia

Pretty much like the title says, does directx in any way use the CUDA libraries/extensions for nvidia cards under the hood?

Basically do the directx libraries, under the hood, are actually making calls to the CUDA cores via CUDA libraries?

Comment: The one word answer is no.

Comment: CUDA is an NVidia only technology. DirectX is vendor-neutral. DirectCompute works on Intel Integrated Graphics, NVidia, and AMD video Direct3D Feature Level 11.0 or later cards. Why are you asking?

Comment: i was curious how to take full control/optimize gaming applications with nvidia cards and thought if CUDA programming was the way.

Comment: Directx talks to the card just like cuda libraries do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is a legitimate one in my opinion.

DirectX is a framework (a bunch of libraries) that provides programming interfaces for graphics, sound, and other peripherals, mainly made for games.
Direct3D, much like OpenGL, is the library that is responsible to communicate with the graphics card. I assume your question was directed at Direct3D.

When Direct3D is invoked, it uses the same multiprocessors that CUDA does, and even more components (e.g. rasterizers). However, Direct3D interfaces directly with the graphics card drivers (in this case, NVIDIA). So basically, both CUDA and Direct3D invoke the NVIDIA drivers, but in slightly different ways.

It is worth noting that pixel/vertex shaders, which are part of Direct3D/OpenGL, actually sparked the idea behind CUDA. Back in 2007, people were writing general purpose scientific code *in pixel shaders*.

P.S. DirectCompute is the closest relative to CUDA DirectX can offer, enabling cross-platform (i.e. non-NVIDIA) GPU development.

Comment: Wow, thanks for clearing that up.  So if CUDA library is specifically designed for their CUDA GPUs, is it in theory more optimized/better for graphics applications?

Comment: Due to specific features in GPUs (such as the texture cache), graphics-oriented computations are more suited for CUDA. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you again.  So what edge does directx11or12 have over CUDA programming?  Can you use both in a single application?

Comment: @TalBen-Nun Why would you say that graphics-oriented computations are more suited for CUDA? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant computations that are two-dimensional, like convolution and median filtering. You are correct, I should've said "image processing and computer graphics" instead.

Comment: @dave As answered, 3D graphics use additional components of the GPU that CUDA cannot. DirectX can be used in conjunction with CUDA using the DirectX Interop (interoperability) API. For an example, see the "simpleD3D11Texture" example in the CUDA SDK.